# How to use SF symbols in Swift Charts for points using symbol() modifiers?

Tags: swift, swiftui, charts, sf-symbols

I want to use the iOS16 Swift Charts to plot my data using the SF symbols with either `symbol()` or `symbol(by:)` modifiers. Currently, I'm using the SwiftUI view in place of the symbol - not as neat as I think it could be with symbols modifiers.

Here's my working code thus far:

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct Vitals {
    var time: Int
    var pulse: Int
    
    init(time: Int, pulse: Int) {
        self.time = time
        self.pulse = pulse
    }
}

var data: [Vitals] = [
    Vitals(time: 5, pulse: 74),
    Vitals(time: 10, pulse: 68),
    Vitals(time: 15, pulse: 73),
    Vitals(time: 20, pulse: 78),
    Vitals(time: 25, pulse: 70),
    Vitals(time: 30, pulse: 69)
]
```

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Chart(data, id: \.time) {
            PointMark(
                x: .value("Time", $0.time),
                y: .value("Vitals", $0.pulse)
            )
            .annotation(position: .overlay, alignment: .center) {
                VStack(spacing: 4) {
                    Image(systemName: "apple.logo")
                }
            }
        }
        .chartYAxis() {
            AxisMarks(position: .leading)
        }
        .frame(height: 400)
        .padding(50)
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution is as simple as this (use [symbol(symbol:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts/chartcontent/symbol(symbol:)) instance method):

```
public func symbol(@ViewBuilder symbol: () -> View) -> some ChartContent
```

Here's the code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Chart(data, id: \.time) {
            PointMark(x: .value("Time", $0.time),
                      y: .value("Vitals", $0.pulse)
            )
            .symbol {
                Image(systemName: "apple.logo")
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .font(.system(size: 17))   // default
            }
        }
        .chartYScale(domain: 0...120)
        .frame(height: 300)
        .padding(30)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you! I don't suppose you'd be able to flesh that out a bit, by showing how to control the size of those symbols, and also to show them in the Chart legend? Asking for a friend...

Comment: I've updated the answer (with `font(...)` method). For adding chart legend use `chartLegend(...)` modifier – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73255252/custom-legends-in-swift-charts-for-ios-16